# jquery change css for different ids with the same class

Tags: jquery, css, function

i have 3 divs with the same class.

```
<div id="qq1" class="cl">sentence</div>
<div id="qq2" class="cl">sentence</div>
<div id="qq3" class="cl">sentence</div>
```

well i'd like to know how can i write correct code for entering mouse calling with one function for 3 divs (calling cl class) and returning the correct id for change css.for ex:

```
<script>
$('.cl').live('mouseenter', function() {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('currentId').css("background-color", "#99cc33");
    $('currentId').css("color", "white");
});
$('.cl').live('mouseleave', function() {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('currentId').css("background-color", "white");
    $('currentId').css("color", "#404040");
});
</script>
```

But there's something wrong 'cause it doesn't work

Comment: I would replace the correct answer as nnnnnn's answer. That answer is more correct and should be the one people follow should they have a similar problem and find this question to help guide them. On stack overflow it is not about who answered "a" correct answer first, but the best answer to the problem. nnnnnn got it more correct first.

Comment: @7thkernel - you're simply changing the foreground and background colors when the mouse enters and leaves a `<div>` with the `cl` class... I'm curious, why aren't you just doing this with a `:hover` in a CSS rule? No Javascript is required.

Comment: @Stephen P it's obvious but my question is how can i do in js, dont you? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't ever use the `currentId` variable, instead you try to use a string that contains the letters c, u, r, etc., `'currentId'`.

To make it work with that variable you would need to say `$('#' + currentId).css()` - so if, e.g., `currentId` is `'qq1'` then in effect you would be saying `$('#qq1').css()`.

However you don't need the id at all because you can simply use `$(this)`:

```
$('.cl').live('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).css({"background-color" : "#99cc33",
                 "color" : "white"});
});

$('.cl').live('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    $(this).css("color", "#404040");
});
```

Within a jQuery event handler `this` refers to the DOM element itself, while `$(this)` creates a jQuery object for that element so that you can call jQuery methods on it. Note that the [`.css()` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) accepts a map of multiple properties so you can set them all with a single call - I've shown that syntax in the `mouseenter` but not the `mouseleave` so that you can compare.

(Note: not related at all to your question, but if you are using jQuery 1.7+ you should stop using [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) because it has been deprecated in favour of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - there are instructions on the [`.live()` doco page](http://api.jquery.com/live) for how to convert your code. If you are using < 1.7 but > 1.4.2 you should use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).)

Comment: Why was I re-credited for this? Your answer is more correct. Also, you could update your answer to chain the .live().live() calls.

Comment: Thanks @Kai - I didn't chain the calls because I didn't want to put too much new information in the same post when it wasn't directly related to the problem.

Comment: lol - precisely why I didn't mention $(this). I didn't want the response to be too re-written or the reason why the failure was happening may not have been clear. But the haste to reply quickly meant I wasn't thinking to just thoroughly explain the rewrite, which would have been the best way to respond. Anyhow, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$('.cl').live('mouseenter', function() {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + currentId).css("background-color", "#99cc33");
    $('#' + currentId).css("color", "white");
});
$('.cl').live('mouseleave', function() {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + currentId).css("background-color", "white");
    $('#' + currentId).css("color", "#404040");
});
</script>
```

You were attempting to call a variable as a literal string. Remember to use the # id selector then append your variable to that string.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this instead:

```
<script> 
$('.cl').live('mouseenter', function() { 
    $(this).css("background-color", "#99cc33"); 
    $(this).css("color", "white"); 
}); 
$('.cl').live('mouseleave', function() { 
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id'); 
    $(this).css("background-color", "white"); 
    $(this).css("color", "#404040"); 
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cl').click(function() {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');

    $("#"+currentId).css();
  });
});
```

this is the basic idea, the rest is just knowledge